# Sharp and good res in render view but blurry and low res after i save it

Tags: animation

[image]So i am trying to make a pixel art with low res(200x150) in blender

When i see my render in render view it looks good and pixaleted but when i save it, image becomes 200x150 and gets blurry.

does anyone know how do i save the exact render in render view [render view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKDiI.png)[image: after i save it]

Comment: The problem is not in the saving, it in the reading application. Use a better image viewer. As it stands this is not really a question about Blender, so it seems off topic here.